# ¿Cómo reorganizar un data.frame?

Tags: r

Tengo un `data.frame` con una determinada estructura:

```
ucba <- data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
ucba

      Admit Gender Dept Freq
1  Admitted   Male    A  512
2  Rejected   Male    A  313
3  Admitted Female    A   89
4  Rejected Female    A   19
5  Admitted   Male    B  353
6  Rejected   Male    B  207
7  Admitted Female    B   17
8  Rejected Female    B    8
9  Admitted   Male    C  120
10 Rejected   Male    C  205
11 Admitted Female    C  202
12 Rejected Female    C  391
13 Admitted   Male    D  138
14 Rejected   Male    D  279
15 Admitted Female    D  131
16 Rejected Female    D  244
17 Admitted   Male    E   53
18 Rejected   Male    E  138
19 Admitted Female    E   94
20 Rejected Female    E  299
21 Admitted   Male    F   22
22 Rejected   Male    F  351
23 Admitted Female    F   24
24 Rejected Female    F  317
```

Y quisiera reformularlo a la siguiente forma:

```
  Dept Male/Admitted Male/Rejected Female/Admitted Female/Rejected
1    A           512           313              89              19
2    B           353           207              17               8
3    C           120           205             202             391
4    D           138           279             131             244
5    E            53           138              94             299
6    F            22           351              24             317
```

Básicamente:

- Agrupamos por departamento
- Sumarizamos en columnas los valores de aceptación / rechazo (`Admit`) y sexo `Gender`.
- La salida final debe ser otro `data.frame` y los nombres de las columnas debieran ser explicativos

Investigué varias opciones (`aggregate` y `xtabs`) que hasta ahora no me convencen del todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa es usar funciones que vienen el el paquete `tidyr`:

Primero unimos las columnas `Gender` y `Admit` usando la función `unite` (funcion opuesta es `separate`):

```
library(tidyr)
ucbau <- unite(ucba, "gender_admit", Gender, Admit, sep = "/")
ucbau
#> # A tibble: 24 x 3
#>       gender_admit   Dept  Freq
#>  *           <chr> <fctr> <dbl>
#>  1   Male/Admitted      A   512
#>  2   Male/Rejected      A   313
#>  3 Female/Admitted      A    89
#>  4 Female/Rejected      A    19
#>  5   Male/Admitted      B   353
#>  6   Male/Rejected      B   207
#>  7 Female/Admitted      B    17
#>  8 Female/Rejected      B     8
#>  9   Male/Admitted      C   120
#> 10   Male/Rejected      C   205
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

Luego *esparcimos* el data frame (lo transformamos a formato ancho) usando la funcion `spread` (la opuesta es `gather`):

```
spread(ucbau, gender_admit, Freq)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>     Dept `Female/Admitted` `Female/Rejected` `Male/Admitted`
#> * <fctr>             <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1      A                89                19             512
#> 2      B                17                 8             353
#> 3      C               202               391             120
#> 4      D               131               244             138
#> 5      E                94               299              53
#> 6      F                24               317              22
#> # ... with 1 more variables: `Male/Rejected` <dbl>
```

Una de las gracias de las funciones del paquete `tidyr` (incluyendo las de `dplyr`) es que tanto el input como el output son  data.frames por lo que es fácil encadenarlas. Además hacen el código más legible pues cada función es un verbo.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`agregate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate)

Una forma algo compleja de leer pero factible, es usar [`aggregate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate) de la siguiente forma:

```
setNames(
     as.data.frame(
          sapply(
               aggregate(Freq ~ Dept, ucba, cbind)
              ,unlist
          )
     ), 
     c("Dept", c(unique(cbind(paste0(ucba$Gender,"/",ucba$Admit)))))
)
```

La salida:

```
  Dept Male/Admitted Male/Rejected Female/Admitted Female/Rejected
1    A           512           313              89              19
2    B           353           207              17               8
3    C           120           205             202             391
4    D           138           279             131             244
5    E            53           138              94             299
6    F            22           351              24             317
```

Explicación:

- Con el [`aggregate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate) inicial, logramos agrupar por `Dept` y creamos una columna que será una lista con los valores de `Freq` de cada subgrupo (`Gender` y `Admit`)
- Con [`sapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) aplicamos la función [`unlist()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/unlist) y "abrimos" la lista en columnas
- Por último convertimos todo a un `data.frame` y configuramos los nombres de columna por algo más claro usando [`setNames()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/setNames).

#### [`xtabs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/xtabs)

Mucho más sencillo es usar las tablas de contingencia mediante [`xtabs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/xtabs), para lograr la salida que buscamos, simplemente podemos hacer:

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Dept+paste0(Gender,"/",Admit), data = ucba)
```

Esto genera directamente la salida esperada, el problema es que es un objeto de la clase `xtabs table` y no un `data.frame`, entonces lo deberemos convertir, pero mantener la estructura de la tabla hay que usar [`as.data.frame.matrix()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.matrix):

```
as.data.frame.matrix((xtabs(Freq ~ Dept+paste0(Gender,"/",Admit), data = ucba)))
```

Comment: ¿Por qué algunos de los textos formateados como código de tu respuesta son enlaces? Cuando pincho en ellos me dirige a una web que aparece un mensaje de que no tengo acceso al objeto solicitado.

Comment: @JuanLuis, Desde hace unos días he notado esto, incluso con  enlaces a este sitio desde un búsqueda de Google. Lástima, por que me parecía lo más oficial y rápido con respecto a la documentación de R

Comment: @JuanLuis, al menos actualice esta pregunta apuntando todo al sitio: www.rdocumentation.org. Me voy a cambiar de proveedor de referencias ;-)

Comment: Ahora sí. La verdad es que la respuesta es mucho más didáctica de esta manera.